24.04 AMD MSI gaming : I can boot into recovery mode. System locks up if it launches
I can get to recovery mode I can get to the prompt.  What should I do?  I ran all the options in recovery mode screen.  If i start the system normally it locks up hard.  Sometimes immediately sometimes after a few minutes usually while typing or using mouse.
I had a terrible time installing this as it would lock up even the live session no matter what.  Eventually at about the 20th reboot it got through the whole install process.
AMD Radeon R9380 graphics
MSI 970 Motherboard AMD FX 8350 chip
Should I be looking for specific updates?  Should I try to update the system with SUDO which I'll have to look up the commands I forget how to use it.
I feel like I'm getting close, I hate to admit how much time I've spent doing this !
thx

I did the update still locks up.  I guess I’ll try an older kernel maybe .  Guessing.  As soon as I move the mouse or while I’m typing it seems it locks up

Installed xubuntu from command line same.  Locks right up.  So frustrating.  Anyone want to recommend another distro?  Cant keep sitting here hard restarting the computer .
